# HTML and corresponding DOM Tree

Tags: html, dom

I have to create a DOM Tree for class and just wanted to know if I did it correctly before I turn it in. If anyone could confirm for me that it is correct or point out what I did wrong I would appreciate it. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<title>Lab 2</title>
<link href="lab2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="lab2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Images</h1>
<div id="content">
<img id="display" src="images/blank.gif" alt="Blank Image"><br />
<button onclick="change()" id="changeImage">Display Image</button>
<h2 id="description">The image is blank</h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: The `homework` tag is deprecated. Please do not use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `img` and the `h2` are children of the `div`, not siblings.

Also, what happened to the `button` and the `br`?

Comment: Ah thank you. That makes sense. Are the button and br children as well?

Comment: @user1157541 - They sure are.